# How to chain network calls in Android when responses from each is dependent on the subsequent call

Tags: android, callback, android-networking

I have three different network calls to be made :

- The first gets list of data from server.
- On the basis of list index from the above response, app makes a another network call.
- Finally the the third network call is made based on the response from above and content is set on the textview.

**What I have tried**:

- Added the network calls in loop, But the problem is that the after the first network call, the list iterates and then is terminated while callbacks from other network calls are not made according to their sequence.

I want to have some mechanism, so that while iterating list, it should wait, and make other callbacks on sequence, and when the data is successfully sets to text fields then iterate again and do it same for all  list index.. here is my code ??

Can anyone help me please

```
public void setDataToTextBox(String text) {
 mytextbox.setText(text.toString());
}

public void getData(final int LID) {
 RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter(this, "http://localhost:2000/api");
 ResponseDemoRepository responseDemoRepository = adapter.createRepository(ResponseDemoRepository.class);

 responseDemoRepository.findAll(new ListCallback < ResponseDemo > () {
  @Override
  public synchronized void onSuccess(List < ResponseDemo > responseDemoList) {
   for (int i = 0; i < responseDemoList.size(); i++) {

    if (responseDemoList.get(i).getLID() == 1) {
     getnewID(responseDemoList.get(i).getTaskAssignmentID());
    }
   }
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void onError(Throwable t) {}

 });
}

public void getnewID(final int TaskID) {

 RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter(this,
  "http://localhost:2000/api");
 TaskAssignmentsDemoRepository taskAssignmentsDemoRepository =
  adapter.createRepository(TaskAssignmentsDemoRepository.class);


 taskAssignmentsDemoRepository.findById(TaskID, new ObjectCallback < TaskAssignmentsDemo > () {

  @Override
  public synchronized void onSuccess(TaskAssignmentsDemo object) {
   getNewData(object.getData01()); // object.getData01() is int #
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void onError(Throwable t) {
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
 });
}

public void getNewData(final int ID) {
 RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter(this, "http://localhost:2000/api");
 Hadith_Repository hadithRepository = adapter.createRepository(Hadith_Repository.class);


 hadithRepository.findById(ID, new ObjectCallback < Hadith > () {
   @Override
   public synchronized void onSuccess(Hadith object) {
    setDataToTextBox(object.getHadith_data());
   }
  }

  @Override public synchronized void onError(Throwable t) {
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
 });

}
```

Comment: Instead of a loop, you can just do one call of `getData()`, and have a listener in place that you call back once the last method has finished its call, this will trigger a callback to your listener method and in there you would call `getData()` with the next ID.
The last method `getNewData()` should figure out if the calls that was just made is the last one so that it doesn't trigger a callback then!

Comment: thanks for  your reply.. Can you please add some snipit of code, which can help me to understand in better way that what exactly you are saying

Comment: @Rehan Have you tried / read about Asynctask  ?  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Can you please share where you're calling that loop of methods so I can show my solution?